# The excel sheet navigate buttons don't work/remain unavailable

Tags: excel

Its very strange that the small sheet navigation buttons (those look like small arrows) in the lower left of windows, either remain fully grayed/unavailable (when workbook is of 2-3 sheets only), or let me navigate only to a few limited sheets (when its more than 3-4 sheets).

[image]

Scroll lock is also off.
I'm on windows 11 and am using licensed version of MS Office 2021. Though I am using Asap Utilities add on, but I've also experimented by turning the same off (i.e. no addons).

Can anybody pls help as to what's going on (google didn't help).

Comment: It is greyed out when you see all tabs and no more are hidden on the left or right.

Answer (score 1):

All credit of this answer goes to the comment (answer) written by @prema
(later changed to @WeAreOne)

copy paste:
"It is greyed out when you see all tabs and no more are hidden on the left or right."